# Range controlls are no longer working after putting them into form (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I wrote a simple js code to display the range input value:

```
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

function settings3_newDistance() {
    var slider = document.getElementById(
    "settings3_newDistance"
    ).value;
    document.getElementById(
    "settings3_newDistance_value"
     ).value = slider;
}
```

And it works perfectly when the `input type="range"` is not inside the form. After I wrapped everything in a form, it all suddenly stopped working. I tried to change the submit button to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I changed the button type from `submit` to just `button`. But it still doesn't display the current value of the slider/range input. The console says: `settings3_overallDistance is not a function`, but it is defined as `oninput="settings3_overallDistance()"` in the range/slider input properties. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Range/slider input with the output box (value output) code:

```
    <div class="form-control">
        <span
          ><input
             id="settings3_modernisedDistance"
             name="settings[3][modernisedDistance]"
             value="0"
             min="0"
             max="100"
             step="1"
             type="range"
             oninput="settings3_modernisedDistance()"
             required=""
             class="form-control" /></span
           ><input
            type="text"
            id="settings3_modernisedDistance_value"
            value="0"
            placeholder="Distance"
            readonly="readonly"
           />
    </div>
<script>
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  function settings3_modernisedDistance() {
      var slider = document.getElementById(
        "settings3_modernisedDistance"
       ).value;
       document.getElementById(
         "settings3_modernisedDistance_value"
       ).value = slider;
       }
  </script>
```

Now the code form the bottom of the form:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
    Reset
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    Submit
  </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: That's not function declaration... that's EventListener assignment. There is not enough code shown to determine your issue.

Comment: Do you think that disabling the form from submitting would help? Something has happened that javascript can no longer write output to a read-only text input which I am using.

Comment: I agree with StackSlave - there is too little code to determine anything for definite. Please post more of your code.

Comment: Now I have included some more code that is relevant to this issue. Please take a look.